# Is it possible to differentiate whether an argument is a string or number? in PHP

Tags: php, string, types, numbers, arguments

Suppose this

```
function Args($a) {
  if (/*HOW*/) {
    echo "the argument is a pure number";
  } else {
    echo "the argument is a string";
  }
}

Args(4); -> the argument is a pure number
Args("4"); -> the argument is a string
```

According to the function and the example, how I can to obtain the difference, according to the type argument?

Answer (score 4):

Use the builtin-functions `is_int($value)` or `is_string($value)`

The manual for is_int is [here](http://de3.php.net/is_int),
the manual for is_string [here](http://de3.php.net/is_string)

Comment: It's actually `is_integer`. You can also use `is_numeric` to determine if the string is a parseable one; that is, if it's something like `"1.00"`.

Comment: @JimmySawczuk: `is_integer` is actually an alias of the function `is_int` http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-integer.php

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Args($a) {
    $type=gettype($a);
    echo "the argument is a ".$type;
}
```